# How to give the path of the images stored in assets folder?

Tags: android

In my application I need to **store the images in assets folder** and should display them. I have tried all ways but still the image is not displaying. **I have tried using Asset Manager, InputStream and Uri but no result finally**. Please help me with this issue. I am struugling a lot ...Can u please tell how to give the path....for example I saved my images in assets folder then I am giving as

```
  InputStream val=getAssets().open("/assets/62.gif");
```

Is that path correct? Please tell me where I went wrong..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think the problem is of gif image use any other like png

Comment: Hi I kept png img also but still it didnt worked for me....

Answer (score 2):

Asset file is accessible through following URI:

```
file:///android_asset/62.gif
```

Just open it and use

Comment: Hi I tried as                                            InputStream is2 = getAssets().open("file:///android_asset/test3.png"); Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);           ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bmImg); ....    but even then the image is not displaying...please suggest me where I am going wrong

Comment: @Sweety you shouldn't try getAssets().open() - just open() w/o getAssets() prefix

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
InputStream val=getAssets().open("62.gif");
```

Comment: Hi I tried like InputStream val=getAssets().open("62.gif");
but still no result..

Comment: It is not displaying any error in logcat..                       11-17 16:53:58.343: INFO/System.out(381): after lv users              11-17 16:53:58.393: INFO/class com.splash.Select$ListAdapter(381): 62.gif

Comment: It is just displaying the image name